# Set Content-type in the request header with application.properties in Spring Reactive

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-webflux, reactive

I need to set content-type for a rest call as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" . I can do it with code by adding below to @RequestMapping

`produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"`

But I want to know if this can be achieved without any code change, just by adding any property in `application.properties`. Tried by adding below properties, but didn't worked:

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force-response=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are working with spring-webflux, referring to [Content Type Resolvers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.1/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-config-content-negotiation)
You can configure the response media type by adding a `WebFluxConfigurer`, and the media type can be read from *application.properties* using `@Value`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Value("${mediaType}")
    private String mediaType;

    public void configureContentTypeResolver(RequestedContentTypeResolverBuilder builder) {
        builder.fixedResolver(MediaType.parseMediaType(mediaType));
    }
}
```

And *application.properties*

```
mediaType=application/json;charset=UTF-8
```